# JSF can't get HttpSession when convertNumber's attribute pattern retrieve it's value from managedBean

Tags: java, validation, jsf

I got this error:

```
" /webapp/monitor.xhtml @29,113 pattern="#{customerController.maskValue}" An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean customerController]
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /webapp/monitor.xhtml @29,113 pattern="#{customerController.maskValue}" /webapp/monitor.xhtml @29,113 pattern="#{customerController.maskValue}" An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean customerController
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.BeanPropertyTagRule$DynamicPropertyMetadata.applyMetadata(BeanPropertyTagRule.java:123) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ConvertNumberHandler.setAttributes(ConvertNumberHandler.java:105) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyAttachedObject(ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:135) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletsAttachedObjectHandler.applyAttachedObject(FaceletsAttachedObjectHandler.java:98) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:76) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:199) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) ~[glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar:2.0.0.0_2-1-20]
```

This happen when in the @PostConstruct method i try to get the HttpSession.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception{
    FacesContext contextFaces = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext contexExtern = contextFaces.getExternalContext();
    HttpSession session;
    String userRequest;
    session = (HttpSession)contextExtern.getSession(false);
    if (session == null){
        throw new Exception("Can't get HttpSession. ");
    }
 }
```

In the view i got a convertNumber where the attribute pattern retrieve his value from the managedBean

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="body">

        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" escape="false" />

        <h:form id="formMain">

            <p:panel id="client" style="margin-bottom:10px;">

                <p:layout style="width:1330px; height:140px; min-width:1330px; min-height:140px;" >
                    <p:layoutUnit id="dataClient" position="west" resizable="false" size="500" minSize="500" maxSize="500">

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                            <p:outputLabel for="client" value="Client :"/>
                            <p:inputMask id="client" value="#{customerController.idClient}" required="true" title="Client " mask="99999999" maxlength="8" size="10" requiredMessage="Client is requiered" autocomplete="off"/> 

                            <p:outputLabel for="nameClient" value="Name:" />
                            <h:outputText id="nameClient" value="#{customerController.client}" title="Name Client">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#{customerController.maskValue}" />
                             </h:outputText>

                            <p:outputLabel for="adminMain" value="Admin:"/>
                            <p:outputLabel id="adminMain" value="#{customerController.adminMain}" title="Admin"/>

                            <p:commandButton value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search" ajax="false" action="#{customerController.searchClient()}" title="Push to search" oncomplete="PF('loaders').clearFilters()"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>

                    </p:layoutUnit>
                </p:layout>

            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

But when i change de value of the pattern attribute to something like `#######`, instead `#{customerController.maskValue}` there's no problem to get the `HttpSession`, probably because it don't have to call the `managedBean`. Any ideas for this behavior?

Comment: is this your running code? Because there are some typo here :  `ExternalContext contexoExterno = contextoFaces.getExternalContext()`. The `contextoFaces` variable is undeclared. There is `contexoFaces` and this is null. You should write here `contextFaces`.

Comment: @TheBitman sorry for that, is already fixed.